# Reverse Proxy Wordpress with Lighttpd

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I am deploying an application and a Wordpress installation on AWS.  I have Wordpress set up under Apache on an EC2, and my application under Lighttpd, and I want to reverse-proxy Wordpress through the application node.  This works fine, I just set up the reverse proxy in Lighttpd as so:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/blog" {
        proxy.server = (
                "/blog" => ( "blog" => ( "host" => "123.456.789.123", "port" => 80 ))
        )
}

url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(.*?)$" => "/index.php/$1"
)
```

However, the issue is in the rewrite.  When I enable rewriting, it catches it before the reverse proxy, and routes to `index.php` on the application server.  I need it to not rewrite if it's going to the blog.  I tried various regex matches and other configurations, but I haven't been able to get it to support rewriting and proxying *at the same time*.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say make your rewrite pattern ignore the paths that are pending for a proxying, but keep the config the same otherwise:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^((?!/blog).*)$" => "/index.php/$1"
)
```

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't get it to work.  The answer I just posted worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by placing another rewrite entry to match `"blog"` before the `index.php` rewrite.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/blog" {
        proxy.server = (
                "/blog" => ( "blog" => ( "host" => "123.456.789.012", "port" => 80 ))
        )
}

url.rewrite-once = (
        "^/blog(.*)" => "$0",
        "^(.*?)$" => "/index.php/$1",
)
```

Since it's using `rewrite-once`, it will stop at the first match and let it fall through to the proxy server.